# Unknown file extension error after adding 'type: module' to package.json

Tags: typescript, package.json, nodemon, ts-node

I'm working in TypeScript, using modern import statements. Running `nodemon` (which then uses `ts-node`) this obviously results in `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. Fair enough, so I added `"type": "module"` to my `package.json` file. Without changing anything else, the new error now reads: `TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for .../file.ts`. Keep in mind that the exact same configuration - before adding `"type":"module"` ran the `.ts` files just fine. Nodemon is also still using ts-node correctly, as witnessed by the line above the error: `[nodemon] starting ts-node src/file.ts`

So I'm confused: Without using `"type":"module"` and modern imports, everything works just fine. Adding modern imports adds a rightful error. Trying to fix that with `"type":"module"` creates strange behavior though.

I also tried removing all content from my main .ts file, only adding a console.log statement. Without `"type":"module"` in my package.json file, this prints to the log just fine. Adding `"type":"module"` back immediately results in the unknown file extension error again.

Simply put:

This works fine:

```
// File.ts
console.log("test")

// package.json
{
    ...
}

// Output
test
```

This results in an error:

```
// File.ts
console.log("test")

// package.json
{
    "type": "module",
    ...
}

// Output
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for .../file.ts
```

I'm sure I'm doing *something* wrong, but these kinds of errors don't really make it easy to figure out for yourself. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: You might want to use `tsc -w` in one shell then `nodemon path/to/output.js` instead.

Comment: @kellys Is that a known best practice, or just a workaround?

Comment: In my experience `nodemon` with `ts-node` is really just a pain to configure compared to two commands `tsc -w` and then running `nodemon` on the output.

Comment: Appreciate the work around, but I find it incredible that ts-node doesn't actually do the one thing it is supposed to do. The lack of answers to this question suggests that its not that common a problem so how are people getting this to work?

Comment: There is a bigger issue with ts-node and node version 20.x / 21.x when using ESM loader:

https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/1997

This means, whenever you have `type:module` in your package.json, or you try to use `.mts` file extension, you can not anymore use `ts-node --esm` or `ts-node-esm` or `{ ts-node: { esm: true } }` in your tsconfig.json. There is a workaround. Use `node --loader ts-node/esm  myfile.mts` , but people in thread above report that line numbers in error stack trackes are broken then. Other solution: downgrade to node 18.x

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75819049/use-ts-node-to-run-mts/77550098#77550098