# Use ts-node to run .mts

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

Is there a way to use ts-node to run `.mts` files. I've tried to do so but am getting errors on imports (from within the .mts file).

```
Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
```

I don't want to do this because I'm not confident how it will impact the broader repo.

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module
```

I can live with an `.mjs` but I'd like everything to be TS.

Edit:

https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/1007

[ts-node execute typescript with module import and module defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63445821/ts-node-execute-typescript-with-module-import-and-module-defined)

Comment: Consider trying using https://github.com/esbuild-kit/tsx as a more modern solution

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have this typescript file

```
// myfile.mts
const x: string = "I am a MTS file";
console.log(x);
```

## Solution for node 18

```
ts-node --esm myfile.mts
```

## Solution for node 20

Use the following syntax

```
node --loader ts-node/esm  myfile.mts
```

The same issue will happen with `.ts` file extension if you use `type: module` in package.json. See also [Unknown file extension error after adding 'type: module' to package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72060450/unknown-file-extension-error-after-adding-type-module-to-package-json)

The reason seems to be that node 20 made a breaking change with regards how loaders are handled: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/1997 . Some people report that this solution has the downside that line numbering is broken in stack traces.

### Configuration used for example above

- Node 20.2.0
- ts-node 10.9.1

**tsconfig.json**: Either use no tsconfig.json at all, or use a very simple tsconfig.json like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "NodeNext"
  }
}
```

Comment: I got Node 20, ts-node 10.9.2 and get `Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'ts-node' imported from /Users/my-repo`. I used `node --loader ts-node/esm  myfile.mts`

Answer (score 2):

try `ts-node --esm index.mts`
If that gives you errors, you may have to configure an alternate tsconfig.js, see [How can I generate a tsconfig.json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36916989)

You can specify an alternate tsconfig on the command line with the --project argument, e.g.

`ts-node --project ./other-tsconfig.json --esm index.mts`

Comment: TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".mts" for /Users/me/WebstormProjects/drive-test/src/accessTokens.mts

Comment: Looks like this depends on the runtime environment. I got it working with ts-node --esm index.mts for node 18. But it does not anymore work for node 20. There I am getting ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION ( using ts-node 10.9.1 )

Comment: @MichaelS node 18 did not work either with `ts-node --esm index.mts`, error `TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".mts" for /Users/..`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this example will be helpful!

The following example worked for me.

Be mindful of the module system you are using (CommonJS or ESM).

In CommonJS, you should require the ".ts" files directly:

```
// File: ./src/main.cts
// The package.json must NOT contain {"type": "module"}
// In tsconfig.json, use {"module": "CommonJS|Node16|NodeNext"}
// Use the command: node --require ts-node/register ./src/main.cts
const { add: cjs_add } = require("./math.cts");
console.log(cjs_add(3, 5));

// File: ./src/math.cts
module.exports.add = function add(a: number, b: number): number {
    return a + b;
}
```

In TypeScript (ESM), import the compiled files (e.g., .ts files become .js, .mts files become .mjs):

```
// File: ./src/main.mts
// For node18, use: npx ts-node --esm ./src/main.mts
// For node20, use: node --loader ts-node/esm ./src/main.mts
import { add as esm_add } from "./math.mjs";
console.log(esm_add(0, 1));

// File: ./src/math.mts
export function add(a: number, b: number): number {
    return a + b;
}
```