# TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" in node v20.5.1

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, compiler-errors, ts-node

When running NPM run Dev is giving the error: TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts", can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Node Version: 20.5.1

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "transform": "typescript-transform-paths"
      }
    ]
  },
  "include": ["/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true
  }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "name-project",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "server.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "dotenv -e .env.test jest -i",
        "test:coverage": "dotenv -e .env.test jest -i -- --coverage",
        "dev": "nodemon src/server.ts",
        "build": "npx tsc --outDir dist",
        "start": "node dist/src/server.js",
        "prisma:push:test": "dotenv -e .env.test npx prisma db push"
    },
    "prisma": {
        "seed": "ts-node prisma/seed/index.ts",
        "execute": "node dist/prisma/seed/index.js"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "privacy",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "@joi/date": "^2.1.0",
        "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "dayjs": "^1.11.7",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
        "dotenv-cli": "^6.0.0",
        "express": "^4.18.1",
        "express-async-errors": "^3.1.1",
        "http-status-codes": "^2.2.0",
        "joi": "^17.6.2",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@faker-js/faker": "^7.6.0",
        "prisma": "^4.12.0",
        "@prisma/client": "^4.12.0",
        "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
        "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
        "@types/dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "@types/express": "^4.17.14",
        "@types/http-status": "^1.1.2",
        "@types/jest": "^29.1.1",
        "@types/joi": "^17.2.3",
        "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.9",
        "@types/node": "^20.4.2",
        "@types/supertest": "^2.0.12",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.1.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.1.0",
        "babel-jest": "^29.1.2",
        "eslint": "^8.24.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
        "eslint-config-standard-with-typescript": "^23.0.0",
        "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.5.5",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
        "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
        "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.0.1",
        "jest": "^29.1.2",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.19",
        "supertest": "^6.3.0",
        "ts-jest": "^29.0.3",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
        "typescript": "^4.8.4"
    },
    "repository": "privacy"
}
```

We tried reinstalling the typescript globally, we tried using ts-node --esm to run and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72060450/unknown-file-extension-error-after-adding-type-module-to-package-json and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75819049/use-ts-node-to-run-mt

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and after exploring I found that Node.js v20 has some breaking changes.

I have found a workaround by using this command `node --loader ts-node/esm your-file.ts`.

So you can change your `dev` script to something like this:
`"dev": "nodemon --exec node --loader ts-node/esm src/server.ts"`

For further info you check this issue on Github: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/1997